# compare current and previous line in java with scanner

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file line by line using Scanner. and also compare the current line with the previous line to see if a specific string is there.
However I am getting a null pointer exception.

```
String previousLine = null;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("Importing") && !previousLine.contains("Importing")) {  {
        System.out.println(previousLine);
    }
    previousLine = line;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time `previousLine` is still null, because it has not yet been set. That is why you're getting a `NullPointerException`. Change your code to following:

```
String previousLine = null;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(previousLine != null && line.contains("Importing") && !previousLine.contains("Importing")) { 
        System.out.println(previousLine);
    }
    previousLine = line;
}
```

Note the null check in the `if`. This way the first line is read and not compared to the `previousLine` (because that is not set). So the `if` is just skipped and the execution contiues with the second line. But this time the previous one has been set and thus it will work again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(line.contains("Importing") && !previousLine.contains("Importing")) {  {
```

with

```
if(line.contains("Importing") && previousLine != null && !previousLine.contains("Importing")) {  {
```

The varaible `previousLine` is null when you read the very first line. That's why you get an NPE. You are setting a string to it from the second line onward. So you should be good. By the way, there is a very clear guide line on StackOverflow on how to solve an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `previousLine` with empty String instead of null.

`String previousLine = "";`